# Understanding the use of SiteEdit_config.xml file in DD4T/XPM integration

Tags: experience-manager, dd4t, 2013-sp1

I'm integrating XPM into a DD4T website.
I have the SiteEdit_config.xml file in my application root - but I wanted to double check my understanding of how this file is used.

From the [source code on GitHub.com](https://github.com/dd4t/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/blob/master/dotnet/DD4T.Mvc/SiteEdit/SiteEditService.cs), if your style is set to **SiteEdit2012**, and not **SiteEdit**, the attributes that control blueprint context in this file (*componentPublication*, *pagePublication*, *publishPublication*) are effectively ignored - **is that correct?**

```
<contextPublication id="36" componentPublication="29" pagePublication="32" publishPublication="36" />
```

The OTB SiteEdit helpers will only check that the publication Id of your DD4T exists as the `id` attribute in a `contextPublication` element, with BluePrint context left to XPM itself.

I'm looking at simplifying future site rollouts and if can I remove the need to keep updating this file just to add a new `id` attribute, in favour of a traditional web.config key, I think I will.

Answer (score 8):

OK - Looks like for XPM or style="SiteEdit2012" you can just go with an empty **SiteEdit_config.xml**  file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteEdit enabled="true" style="SiteEdit2012" tridionHostUrl="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx">
  <contextPublications/>
</siteEdit>
```

This enabled XPM without having to implement a `<contextPublication>` node for every site you're enabling.

Comment: Yeah we could do with fixing this really, it's non-obvious.